# How to shorten "Helping People with Disabilities Live at Home" to 40 characters

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I'm looking for a shorter way to state the phrase "Helping People with Disabilities Live at Home", it's 45 characters, which is too long for a Facebook tagline.

Comment: Disability Home-assist

Comment: This site isn't a crowd-source-your-marketing service.

Comment: It's not a marketing service that I work for; it's a non-profit.

Comment: @curiousdannii Seriously, did you read the phrase?

Comment: "Helping the Disabled Live at Home"

Comment: @leeand00 I didn't say you worked for a marketing service, I said you wanted us to provide you with a free marketing service, but that's not what this site is for.

Answer (score 2):

> Helping People with Disabilities Stay Home

That is 42 characters including spaces. I personally would not change "People with Disabilities" to "the Disabled". It may be proper grammar, but people generally do not like to be classified into a subgroup of humanity. **People** with Disabilities is much more human than **the disabled**.

Comment: This just your opinion, people with disabilities very often call themselves the Disabled as a group. There are plenty of associations, sites, societies, etc: http://www.regattaforthedisabled.org/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riding_for_the_Disabled_Association

Comment: Yes, I intended it to be clear that was my opinion when I said "personally". I'm sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: "Stay Home" there, instead of "Live at Home", conveys an entirely different meaning...  as if we want them all to stay home so that they stay out of our public places and we don't have to deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

> Helping the Disabled Live at Home

The + Adjective is a grammatical construct to define a group of people. This usage is referred to in the article usage section of grammar books as in the following example:

Usage of the definite article 'the' on [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article)

> With adjectives like rich, poor, elderly, unemployed to talk about
>   groups of people:
>
> - Life can be very hard for the poor.
> - I think the rich should pay more taxes.
> - She works for a group to help **the disabled**.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem a bit too PC, but ***Helping the Otherly-Abled Live At Home*** gets there in under 40 characters

Comment: Note to everyone: please don't ever say anything like this to describe people with disabilities.

Answer (score -1):

"Helping disabled people to live at home"
39 characters.